# Как создать нужный запрос к VK API?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сформировать PHP-запрос на обновление объявления [объявления](https://vk.com/dev/ads.updateAds)?

Есть [пример запросов в официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests), но не совсем понятно, как его переделать под PHP-запрос для объявления.

Токен доступа получать умею.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
$data = array(
        'access_token' => 'my_access_token',
        'account_id'   => '12345',
        'data'         => json_encode(array(
            'ad_id'  => 8829293932,
            'status' => 1,
        ))
    );
    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/ads.updateAds?v=5.62';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'my user agent');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($curlInfo['http_code'] != 200) {
        print "Error. Something went wrong. CODE: " . $curlInfo['http_code'];
        print "\n $result";
        die();
    }
    else {
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: Получается вот такой вот код: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ggdgudzctaezzp/vk.php?dl=0 при попытке выполнить, то есть перейти на страницу, выдает 500 ошибку

Comment: @Dmitriy Khramov, просто 500, без сообщения об ошибке? у меня, к сожалению, нет токена к API вк, чтобы проверить в чем проблема. Приведенный выше код отрабатывает и возвращается с ошибкой "неверный токен", что верно ибо я указывал случайный набор символов вместо него. Приведите какую-нибудь информацию, о том на каком этапе все валится и с какой ошибкой

Comment: Я готов прислать файл с токенами доступа, только, если не сложно, напишите, пожалуйста, Вашу почту или любое другое удобно средство связи, чтобы можно было отправить файл лично Вам. Код размещен в файле index.php и при попытке перейти на него просто выкидывает 500 ошибку. "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"